# Solved : Retrieving data from firestore delay (1.3s) In React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I think I should use ServerSide-Rendering (SSR) to fast Loading Time

*I was making **todo app** with **react and firebase** . I store data in firestore and there is a problem after user login , app will know userid and it will show user stored **data** with userid . When **React UI** is ready but **user data** are not ready on **app startup** and **refresh** . I  can test by adding **loading state** in app but I don't want it. I want a UserExperience like **localStorage app** (data no delay). I need to know do I need some **backend code** or **SSR***

```
useEffect(() => {
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    setUser(user);
    setUserId(user.uid);
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "users/" + user.uid + "/todos"),
      orderBy("timeStamp", "desc")
    );

    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      settodos(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
      );
      console.log("data rendered");
    });
    // return () => unsub()
  }
```

[Screenshot Network tab ( 1.3s dalay)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWbFA.png)

Comment: That's called Loading. Also you are using setState three times in one function which is not wrong, but not a good one.

Comment: How can I make a good one ? Please guide me Sir

Comment: If you want to test here is Demo [link](https://todolistzee3.netlify.app)   I need good practice Sir Please guide me

Comment: https://next.fireship.io/   I think they use SSR for loading data in Nextjs

Comment: In Next.js, there are staticProps(Paths) and dynamicProps(Paths). StaticProps are created at build time (which means there is almost no loading time) and DynamicProps are created at requested time (which means there may be some loading while creating). I think you have already read all about that in Next.js tutorial. You want to create a todo app for each user with firebase backend which means you need to use DynamicProps(Paths).

Comment: in `if (user) {
    setUser(user);
    setUserId(user.uid); ...`, `setUserId(user.uid)` is not necessary. Everytime you want userId, just use `user.uid`. About good practice, well, honestly, I don't know what is. I just avoid bad practices as much as I can. However, I am stilling writing bad codes till today. I don't think I am right person for that.

Comment: Ok I see . Now I also issue in Auth in my New app . You can test here  https://too.netlify.app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I should use Server-Side-Rendering (SSR) to get rid of loading state .